# get median in overlap time range

Tags: sql, vertica

vertica db, for example, have a table called `revenue`:

```
date             revenue
2016-07-12          1
2016-07-12          10
2016-07-12          5
2016-07-12          3
2016-07-13          7
2016-07-13          120
2016-07-13          22
2016-07-14          5
2016-07-14          17
```

The tricky thing is I don't want median for each date but I want to calculate the median revenue for the timerange >= given each day, for example the result would be like:

```
daterange       median_revenue
>= 2016-07-12         7
>= 2016-07-13         17
>= 2016-07-14         11
```

to be clear:

```
7 = median(1,10,5,3,7,120,22,5,17)
17 = median(7,120,22,5,17)
11 = median(5,17)
```

How could I write a sql script for these daterange? Is there an easy way to query? I don't want to calculate in each daterange then union because there are many days.

Comment: Edit your question with sensible desired results.

Comment: In your expected result using the sample you gave us, can you give the expected values for xxx, yyy and zzz? Are they the sum of the revenue for records >= those dates?

Comment: Hi Ashwin, it is the median. I have updated. cause the example have very few samples so the result is not important. Just want to know the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help?

```
SELECT
    date_table.[date],
    MEDIAN (r.revenue) AS median_revenue
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT [date] FROM revenue) date_table
LEFT JOIN revenue r ON r.[date] >= r_main.[date]
GROUP BY
    date_table.[date]
```

Comment: although you calculate the avg, but give me some hints. see my post below

Comment: my bad, for the typo

Answer (score 1):

just figured out

```
select distinct date, median(revenue) over (partition by date) as rev_median  
from (select a.date,b.revenue 
      from (select distinct date from revenue_test) a 
      left outer join revenue b 
           on a.date<=b.date order by a.date,b.date) a ;`
```